# Entity Framework 7 Update DbContext after migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I've got an existing DB and new WPF project.

**1)** I scaffolded db context with `Scaffold-DbContext` and recieved **DbContext.cs** and a file for each entity that represents a DB tables. That's OK.
Here is example of one of them:

```
public partial class SomeEntity
    {
        public long SomeEntityID { get; set; }
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    }
```

**2)** I've manually updated this entity (no changes in **DbContext.cs**) :

```
public partial class SomeEntity
    {
        public long SomeEntityID { get; set; }
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
    }
```

**3)** I've used `Add-Migration` command. Now I've got a migration file that describes required changes and **DbContextSnapshot.cs**. Snapshot includes changes I've just made with `SomeEntity`. Database is not updated.

**4)** I've used `Update-Database` command. Database updated to match last migration. But my **DbContext.cs** doesn't know anything about changes in DB. It is still the same old good DbContext that I had after scaffolding DB.

Is this OK? Should I now change DbContext manually to match changes that I've made to my entities and applied them to DB? Is there a way to update **DbContext.cs** from DB after changes without 'rescaffolding'? (Because, for example, all comments and attributes in entity files will be lost, because they will be replaced with new ones if I use `Scaffold-DbContext` again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to run scaffolding again, but keep in mind that the generated classes are partial, so you can put your changes in another file